CAN bus accidentally swapped TX and RX is it possible to solve (in firmware) without board rework
I am interfacing an isolated can transceiver with my microcontroller. My schematic is given below.


Accidently TXD is connected to RXD of microcontroller and RXD is connected to TXD of the microcontroller.
My question can I solve this issue without any rework in the board?
May I know firmware persons can help us by doing some changes in thier code and making this interface up.
Is it possible to swap MCU CAN RX and TX in firmware.
Reference manual of the microcontroller is available here.

What does the datasheet say about the options for CAN TX and RX pins? Based on the schematic they appear to be fixed and can't be swapped.

I have never used a MCU that would allow these pins to be routed individually - you typically have to port route the whole CAN controller peripheral as one, and only to certain pins. Check the part of the MCU manual that speaks of "routing registers" or some such.

Please add a link to the user manual and/or programmer's manual, which includes detailed descriptions of all registers, especially of the pin configuration.

https://www.nxp.com/webapp/sps/download/preDownload.jsp?render=true

Well, what should this generic download link provide? :-D (Please add the links to your question, comments are not for additional information. Additionally, if you like to address someone, please add the username like this: @Confused.)

I will add the link in the question.We need to download from there.It will be directly downloaded to your PC

thats not the download link - it looks like you need to sign in to nxp to get the reference manual. Link is here if anyone is interested: https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/s32-automotive-platform/s32k-auto-general-purpose-mcus/s32k1-microcontrollers-for-automotive-general-purpose:S32K1?fpsp=1#documentation

No datasheet & manual available without registration = no business. NXP is a company in rapid customer service decline. Avoid companies like that.

I'd hope that NXP has a GPIO matrix that allows free routing. If not, you're out of luck.
